# respota automatica de e-mail com phpmailer

Tags: php, envio-de-email, phpmailer

Fala galera!

Estou usando o phmailer para enviar e-mail, esta funcionando tudo muito bem no envio porém, gostaria de saber como fazer uma resposta automática através do próprio phpmailer.

Alguém poderia me dá uma dica?

**EDITADO**

PARA OS QUE TIVEREM A MESMA DÚVIDA, SEGUE A SOLUÇÂO:

```
<?php

// Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta phpmailer
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require("../includes/cookie.class.php");

if (!isset($_GET['nome'])) exit('Por favor informe o seu nome');
if (!isset($_GET['mail'])) exit('Por favor informe o seu email');
if (!isset($_GET['msge'])) exit('Por favor preencha o campo mensagem');
/*if (isset($_GET['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $captcha_data = $_GET['g-recaptcha-response'];
}
if (!$captcha_data) {
    echo "<script>alert('Por favor, confirme o captcha.')</script>";
    header("Location: contato");
    exit;
}
*/
$nome = $_GET['nome'];
$mail = $_GET['mail'];
$fone = $_GET['fone'];
$var_msge = $_GET['msge'];

Cookie::Set('nome', nome, Cookie::ThirtyDays);
Cookie::Set('email', mail, Cookie::ThirtyDays);
Cookie::Set('fone', fone, Cookie::ThirtyDays);

$body = "<table style='background: #ccc; width: 100%;' cellpadding='10' border='1' >";
$body = $body ."<tr>";
$body = $body ."<th>NOME</th>";
$body = $body ."<th>E-MAIL</th>";
$body = $body ."<th>TELEFONE</th>";
$body = $body ."<th>MENSAGEM</th>";
$body = $body ."</tr>";
$body = $body ."<tr>";
$body = $body ."<td>".$nome."</td>";
$body = $body ."<td>".$mail."</td>";
$body = $body ."<td>".$fone."</td>";
$body = $body ."<td>".$msge."</td>";
$body = $body ."</tr>";
$body = $body ."</table>";

// Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.site.com"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP
$mail->Port = '587';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usa autenticação SMTP? (opcional)
$mail->Username = 'resposta@site.com'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
$mail->Password = 'SENHA'; // Senha do servidor SMTP

// Define o remetente
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->From = "resposta@himoveis.com"; // Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = "RESPOSTA"; // Seu nome

// Define os destinatário(s)
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->AddAddress('x@site.com', 'X');


// Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)

// Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->Subject  = "CONTATO"; // Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AltBody = "Para visualizar a mensagem utilize um cliente de email compativel com HTML!";

// Define os anexos (opcional)
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
//$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/documento.pdf", "novo_nome.pdf");  // Insere um anexo

// Envia o e-mail
$enviado = $mail->Send();

// Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

// Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
if ($enviado) {

$body = "<table align='center' style='font-size: 18px; color: #fff; background: #000; width: 60%; text-align: center; padding: 30px; margin: 0 auto;' cellpadding='10' border='0' >";
$body = $body ."<tr>";
$body = $body ."<td>Olá <b>".$nome."</b>! 
                        Recebemos a sua proposta, 
                        dentro do prazo de 60min em horário comercial retornaremos o contato.<br><br><br><br><br>
                        Atenciosamente<br><br>
                        <img src='http://site.com/img/logo.png' width='100' alt='logo' /><br><br>
                        Telefone<br>
                        E-mail<br>
                        Etc...<br>
                        </td>";
$body = $body ."</tr>";
$body = $body ."</table>";

// Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.site.com"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP
$mail->Port = '587';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usa autenticação SMTP? (opcional)
$mail->Username = 'respota@site.com'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP
$mail->Password = 'SENHA'; // Senha do servidor SMTP

// Define o remetente
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->From = "resposta@site.com"; // Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = "CONTATO DO SITE.COM."; // Seu nome

// Define os destinatário(s)
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->AddAddress($mail, $nome);


// Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)

// Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$mail->Subject  = "auto-reply"; // Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AltBody = "Para visualizar a mensagem utilize um cliente de email compativel com HTML!";

// Define os anexos (opcional)
// =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
//$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/documento.pdf", "novo_nome.pdf");  // Insere um anexo

// Envia o e-mail
$mail->Send();

// Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();


header('Location: proposta-enviada');
  die();
} else {
echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.<br /><br />";
echo "<b>Informações do erro:</b> <br />" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

Comment: Caso solucionado!

Comment: Qual foi a solução?

Comment: if($enviado){ envia tudo novamente com uma mensagem formatada em html para o e-mail do usuário colocando-o como remetente}, pra facilitar, criei cookies com os dados preenchidos no formulário e armazenei em variáveis.

Comment: Coloca o código completo que pode ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Já esta editado com a solução pronta. Espero ter ajudado.